# Error al consultar con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Todo funciona ok menos cuando le paso el id de usuario con la variable $id_usuario.

Solo me falla con el inner join, dandome el siguiente error,

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in

Crud Usuario contiene,

```
public function usuarioCurso($id_usuario){
    var_dump($id_usuario);
    $db = BaseDatos::conectar();
    $listadoUsuario = [];

    $consultar = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT u.id_usuario, c.id_curso, m.id_mcurso FROM Usuario u
            INNER JOIN mapeo_curso m ON u.id_usuario = m.id_usuario
            INNER JOIN Curso c ON c.id_curso = m.id_curso
            WHERE $id_usuario = u.id_usuario
    ");

    $consultar->execute($id_usuario);

    $consultar->fetchAll();
}
```

Ficha perfil,

```
$usuario = $crud->obtenerUsuario($_GET['id_usuario']);
$listado = $crud->usuarioCurso($usuario['id_usuario']);
```

Comment: El error indica que el parametro `$id_usuario` es un objeto de tipo `Usuario`. Verifica que estes enviando un valor de tipo entero y no un objeto al momento de ejecutar la funcion.

Comment: Ok, voy a probar.

Comment: Prueba algo así: `$consultar = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT u.id_usuario, c.id_curso, m.id_mcurso FROM Usuario u
            INNER JOIN mapeo_curso m ON u.id_usuario = m.id_usuario
            INNER JOIN Curso c ON c.id_curso = m.id_curso
            WHERE u.id_usuario = ?
    ");`  y  el `execute` lo escribes así : `$consultar->execute(array($id_usuario));` Si sigue sin funcionar, pon en la pregunta el resultado de `var_dump($id_usuario);` También tu bucle `for` sobra, ya `fetchAll` crea un array con los datos. Bastaría un `return $consultar->fetchAll();`

Comment: Gracias por la información. Me sigue saliendo el error... Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in, no entiendo muy bien que hay que hacer para que pase un string....

Comment: ¿Qué muestra `var_dump($id_usuario);`?  ¿En la línea del error qué tienes escrito?

Comment: @sergibarca edita tu pregunta y muestra como ejecutas el metodo `usuarioCurso`

Comment: Ya esta editada. Muestra como ejecuta también.

Comment: Sergi por favor, muestra un `var_dump($usuario);`, el objeto `$usuario` debe tener una propiedad o método para obtener su id, y ese es el valor que debes pasar al método `usuarioCurso`. **¿O acaso es el mismo valor que `$_GET['id_usuario']`?**

Comment: Me uno a la pregunta que te han hecho varios: ¿puedes mostrarnos acá qué te sale al ejecutar el `var_dump($id_usuario)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es filtar por `id_usuario` la llamada el método debería hacerse así:

```
$listado = $crud->usuarioCurso($_GET['id_usuario']);
```

Luego, el método debe ser modificado:

- tu consulta está mal escrita, ya que interpretaría que `$id_usuario` es el nombre de una columna. Lo lógico es que `$id_usuario` sea el valor para filtrar, en la consulta de debe representar con un marcador de posición `?`  o de `:nombre` si quisieras. Y luego, pasar en el `execute` el valor que el método recibió en parámetro.
- haces un uso redundante con `fetchAll`. O sea, le dices *que haga lo que ya hizo*, dado que precisamente lo que hace `fetchAll` es devolver un array del conjunto de datos obtenidos.

El código corregido quedaría más o menos así:

```
public function usuarioCurso($id_usuario){
    $db = BaseDatos::conectar();

    $consultar = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT u.id_usuario, c.id_curso, m.id_mcurso FROM Usuario u
            INNER JOIN mapeo_curso m ON u.id_usuario = m.id_usuario
            INNER JOIN Curso c ON c.id_curso = m.id_curso
            WHERE u.id_usuario=?
    ");

    $consultar->execute(array($id_usuario));
    $listadoUsuario=$consultar->fetchAll();
    return $listadoUsuario;

}
```

Comment: Acabo de ver el error... Estoy un poco espeso jajaja Gracias una vez más!!

Comment: Nada, nada... de vez en cuando una pausa de 5 minutos y un café... y las ideas se aclaran. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.